# make a circle progress bar, but animate arc.endAngle (angle >180 degree) stops working in d3.js

Tags: d3.js

I am running D3.js to draw a progress bar in circle shape, which you will see the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/helxsz/bb8ZS/) on jsfiddle , the progress bar has a transition animation.

The main code is

```
var width = 960,
    height = 500,
    twoPi = 2 * Math.PI,
    progress = 0,
    total = 1308573, // must be hard-coded if server doesn't report Content-Length
    formatPercent = d3.format(".0%");

var arc = d3.svg.arc()
    .startAngle(0)
    .innerRadius(0)
    .outerRadius(240);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

var meter = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "progress-meter");

meter.append("path")
    .attr("class", "background")
    .attr("d", arc.endAngle(twoPi));

var foreground = meter.append("path")
    .attr("class", "foreground");

foreground.attr("d", arc.endAngle(twoPi * 0))

foreground.transition().duration(1500).attr("d", arc.endAngle( twoPi * 2/3  ));     

var text = meter.append("text")
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .attr("dy", ".35em");
```

to make the progress bar move, we only need to change to the arc.endAngle(), which is on the line.

```
foreground.transition().duration(1500).attr("d", arc.endAngle( twoPi * 2/3  ));
```

if the angle is less than 180, ( endangle < twoPi*1/2), then the animation works fine, but when the angle is larger than 180, so means endangle >= twoPi*1/2. then the animation would not show, and if you look at the console, you will find many errors on d3.js

```
Error: Problem parsing d="M1.1633760361312584e-14,-190A190,190 0 1.481481481481482e-7,1 -0.000022772330200401806,-189.9999883969182L0,0Z" meeting.html:1
2
Error: Problem parsing d="M1.1633760361312584e-14,-190A190,190 0 2.56e-7,1 -0.00003935058659476369,-189.99997994987467L0,0Z"
```

so what is the exact problem for this, how to solve it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't work because you can't use the standard transition for radial paths. By default, it simply interpolates the numbers without knowing what they represent, so in your case, you end up with some really small numbers (e.g. 1.1633760361312584e-14) which Javascript represents in exponential notation which is not valid for SVG paths.

The solution is to use a custom tween function that knows how to interpolate arcs:

```
function arcTween() {
  var i = d3.interpolate(0, twoPi * 2/3);
  return function(t) {
    return arc.endAngle(i(t))();
  };
}
```

Complete example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/bb8ZS/1/). You may also be interested in [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1346410), which shows how to do it with data bound to the paths.

Comment: Thanks,Lars, this is great helpful :)